# context is incorrect error in async method probleme

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, error

hey guys i'm trying to use some blender commandes inside a async methodes, but it seemes like blender commands don't work insisde async methodes, i will apreciate any help:

```
from bpy import context
import asyncio
import time
import datetime
from spade.agent import Agent
from spade.behaviour import OneShotBehaviour
from spade.message import Message
from spade.template import Template

class ModeChangerAgent(Agent):
    class ModeChangingBehav(OneShotBehaviour):
        async def run(self):
            print(f"Mode Changing Agent : Mode Changer Behaviour is running ... at {datetime.datetime.now().time()}")
            print("Mode Changing Agent : Mode Changing ... ")
            for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
                
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects[2]

            obj_act = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

            if obj_act and obj_act.mode == 'OBJECT':
                    
                
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set_with_submode(mode='OBJECT')
                 
            else:
                pass 
            

            print("Mode Changing Agent : Mode changed to edit mode.")
                        
            #********message to the face changer agent*******************
                        
            msg = Message(to="anotherAgentJID@XMPPserver")     # Instantiate the message
            msg.set_metadata("performative", "inform")  # Set the "inform" FIPA performative
            msg.body = "you can start the face changing!"  # Set the message content
            await self.send(msg)
            print("Mode Changing Agent : message sent!")
            
            msg = await self.receive(timeout=30) # wait for a message for 10 seconds
            if msg:
                print("Mode Changing Agent : Message received with content: {}".format(msg.body))

        async def on_end(self):
            await self.agent.stop()

    async def setup(self):
        print(f"Mode Changing Agent : Mode Changer Agent started at {datetime.datetime.now().time()}")
        b = self.ModeChangingBehav()
        template = Template()
        template.set_metadata("performative", "inform")
        self.add_behaviour(b, template)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #execution**********************    
    modechangeragent = ModeChangerAgent("agentJID@XMPPserver", "password")
    future = modechangeragent.start()
    future.result() # wait for receiver agent to be prepared.

    while modechangeragent.is_alive():
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                
            modechangeragent.stop()
            break
    print("Mode Changer Agent finished")"""
```

and this is the error i get every time and i didn't find a solution:

````
Mode Changing Agent : Mode Changer Behaviour is running ... at 13:51:51.036063
Mode Changing Agent : Mode Changing ...
Exception running behaviour OneShotBehaviour/ModeChangingBehav: Operator bpy.ops
.object.editmode_toggle.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\site-pa
ckages\spade\behaviour.py", line 264, in _step
    await self._run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\site-pa
ckages\spade\behaviour.py", line 253, in _run
    await self.run()
  File "\Text", line 27, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bp
y\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle.poll() failed, context is
incorrect

Mode Changer Agent finished
```
````

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add